# MS Access protect / hide table from user

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a MS Access database with a table `Test` on drive X.

On drive Y I have another MS Access database with two queries querying table `Test`. 
For this, I created a link to the `Test` table.

On top of the two queries I have two forms for the user to edit table `Test`.

- One form only displays parts of table `Test` in a read-only mode.
- With the other form the users can manipulate some of the data in table `Test`.

So far so good. However, in MS Access the user can see table `Test` in the sidebar all Access-objects. Thus, the user can open the original table by clicking on the linked table `Test`.

What I am trying to do is to somehow protect or hide this link to table `Test` so that the users can only manipulate this table via the forms. Is that somehow possible?

Comment: You can right-click the table in the sidebar, choose "Table Properties", and then select the "Hidden" attribute. Does that suffice?

Comment: thanks for your answer. Well, not really. It's grayed out but I can still click on it and edit it. Whatever I can do the user can do as well. But protecting the table via a password wouldnt do the trick either I think because then the table cannot be edited via the forms an queries.

Comment: It sounds like you have "Show Hidden Objects" selected under File > Options > Current Database > Navigation Options...

Comment: Hi Gord, please see my comment below!

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what version of MS Access you have but you can also do things like in the Tools start up menu deselect

Display Database Window

Note however you need to ensure that your application has a nice flow through and that users do not actually need to see things like the form names to navigate the application.

I.e navigation of forms should purely through command buttons on forms.

If you make this change and you are needing to see the window again hold shift down while opening the database and you will see the database window again.

This worked in Access 2003 and I'm pretty sure its available in other versions.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I tried a bit more and what I found out is that you can save your database as a .accde file. This disables a lot of tings such as the layout view so that users are prevented from making any changes to the tables. It also hides the VBA code which is good. The only thing which I do not manage to make is to permanentely hide my linked table. As Gord Thompson suggested, I can hide the table and set the option for "view hidden tables" to false. This let the table disappear. However, in the .accde file you can reset these options. Thus, this is no proper protection